# How to create synthetic fields in java?

Tags: java, reflection

1. How can synthetic fields be created in Java?
2. Can synthetic fields in java only be created at runtime?
   If not: Is there a standard-compliant way to this at compile time (without changing some bytes in the class file)

Comment: Why would you want to create a synthetic field manually? That's kind of against it's specification, since it says "that's something the compiler has done to enabled some specific behaviour". Anything you want to do manually should be visible to the outside as such.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're created by the compiler when "oddities" of the language require them. A simple example of this is using an inner class:

```
public class Test
{
    class Inner
    {
    }
}
```

The `Test.Inner` class will have a synthetic field to represent the appropriate instance of the `Test` class.

We can extend this code slightly to show that field:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (Field field : Inner.class.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + ": " + field.isSynthetic());
        }
    }

    class Inner
    {
    }
}
```

With my compiler, that prints:

```
this$0: true
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's doable, and it's called load-time weaving. Essentially, you will need to define your own ClassLoader that will decide on a class-by-class case whether to do modify a classfile that is bout to be loaded; that means you will need to inspect the binary class that is being loaded, possibly modify it, then pass it on to the JVM for definition/resolving. It's a bit cumbersome, complicated, and prone to ClassCastExceptions (the same class defined in 2 different classloaders will give 2 different classes that are not assignment-compatible).

Note that weaving allows you to do much more: you can add new methods, interfaces, fields, modify the code of existing classes, and more.

There are already tools that can help you - see for example AspectJ as a full-on language modification, or something like BCEL or javassist that allows you to write such weaving tools.

Answer (score 1):

> How can synthetic fields be created in Java?

`synthetic` field is created by Java compiler automatically, in some specific cases.

Examples:

- Help process the Java `assert` keyword - [java.awt.AWTKeyStroke](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.awt.awtkeystroke).[$assertionsDisabled](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/field?classfilelocation=java.awt.awtkeystroke&seq=10&fieldname=%24assertionsDisabled)
- Help process the java `this` keyword - [java.util.AbstractList$Itr](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.util.abstractlist%24itr).[this$0](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/field?classfilelocation=java.util.abstractlist%24itr&seq=4&fieldname=this%240)
- Field in an anonymous inner class - [java.util.AbstractList$SubList$1](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.util.abstractlist%24sublist%241).[val$index](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/field?classfilelocation=java.util.abstractlist%24sublist%241&seq=2&fieldname=val%24index)
- Help process on Enum fields - [java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntryFlag](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.nio.file.attribute.aclentryflag).[$VALUES](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/field?classfilelocation=java.nio.file.attribute.aclentryflag&seq=5&fieldname=%24VALUES)

> Can synthetic fields in java only be created at runtime? If not: Is there a standard-compliant way to this at compile time (without changing some bytes in the class file)

The `synthetic` is generated in compile time by Java compiler. The `.class` file already contains the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag. Although we can always generate Java fields at runtime.

### More Info

- This [article](https://binarydoc.blogspot.com/2019/10/what-is-java-synthetic-class.html) describes the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag in details
- This [link](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/fields?acc_synthetic) lists all `synthetic` fields in JDK