# How can I add a synthetic field to a class?

Tags: java, reflection, synthetic

One of our classes uses reflection to list another class's fields:

```
public List<String> getFieldNames(Class clazz) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    var fields = clazz.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        var encodedName = encodeName(field.getName());
        result.add(encodedName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code breaks in JaCoCo and PIT mutation tests. Their test setups add a synthetic field to `clazz`. Our `encodeName` method cannot digest that field's name.

We will therefore ignore synthetic fields:

```
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (!field.isSynthetic()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To be safe, we'd like to write a unit test for this new `if` condition. The test should call `getFieldNames` with a class with a synthetic field and assert that the return value includes only the non-synthetic fields.

What's the easiest and most reliable way to create a Class with a synthetic field?

Answers to the question [How to create synthetic fields in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298130/how-to-create-synthetic-fields-in-java) suggest that specifying an inner class within our test class should do the job, but apparently this adds a *private* synthetic field, and .getFields() doesn't consider it. Is there a way to create a *public* synthetic field?

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot! `.getFields()` is on purpose. I'd be much happier if we'd be able to specify a public synthetic field.

Comment: I thought a lot, and the only way I could think of was to write the class in Kotlin (maybe Scala also works but I don't know Scala), but that means you would need to include the Kotlin runtime in your project, which is quite big :(